# How to Make a precompiled build of Orchard CMS

Tags: performance, orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`.

What is the best way to make a `precompiled build` of Orchard CMS?

Comment: What do you mean with 'precompiled'? are you want to build Orchard without output source code?

Comment: From what I understand it turns the cshtml files into dll, its good for performance. Its 3th step in this link http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop/  I couldn't do it from what it says

Comment: What error do you get when you follow those steps? That 3rd step will run MSBuild and generate the output in the folder as described

Comment: Haven't worked with MSBuild before, I'll try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is open a command prompt, go to the root directory of your Orchard project and run the command `build precompiled`.

This command will build the entire Orchard solution and prepare all the files that you need to deploy to IIS. You will find those files in the `build\Precompiled` folder. This folder will contain only the binary files of your application and the configuration/manifest files (such as `Module.txt`, `placement.info`, etc). Those are the files you need to run your application in production. Specifically, there will be no source code files in the `build\Precompiled` directory.

Additionally the configuration files are tweaked for maximum performance. For example dynamic compilation and file monitoring is disabled. However, the view files are not precompiled and I'm not sure if that is even possible with Orchard.

Comment: Thanks mate. big help